# Can't run spark-submit with sudo

Tags: sudo, upstart

I don't know if this is a noob question or not, but my various google searches yielded nothing.

When I run my application, which uses spark-submit under the hood, without sudo, it works. But when I use it with sudo, it just says "spark-submit is not found" or whatever that is.

After (not much) further inspection : which spark-submit yields results, sudo which spark-submit does not.

I edited the secure path using sudo visudo, saved changes, still nothing.

EDIT: Wow, I'm dumb as a box of rocks. I added spark's main folder to sudoers file, I should have added /bin of it. Now sudo which spark-submit yields proper result.

But even now, spark-submit is still not being found.

Comment: Have you tried ./usr/bin/spark-submit ? I would first check if it's in my /bin

Comment: If you have found a solution to your question, please write an answer instead of editing it into your question.

Comment: I haven't found a solution, I just found one mistake that was causing it, the problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to run this thing on Makefile, so I changed the Makefile so that it runs /path/to/the/absolute/location/spark-submit instead of just spark-submit and now it just works. Who could have guessed.